Visualizing Matrix Spaces
When thinking about vector spaces a common example is vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is also very common to visualize this space as a set of as arrows in some n-dimensional space, with the typical notions of vector addition and scalar multiplication.
It is also common to think about $n\times n$ matrices forming a vector space. However, I am having trouble visualizing what this might look like. Perhaps thinking about matrices directly is the wrong approach for what I'm after and instead I should try thinking in terms of a space of linear transformations. At any rate, does there exist a convenient analogy - like the arrows in the plane one for vectors - for thinking about / visualizing n-dimensional matrices and if so what is it?

$n\times n$ matrices do correspond to linear transformations, and also to $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$

There are two ways to think about matrices. The first is simply as a vector. The fact the entries are stacked up instead of all in a single row or column is immaterial. The other is as a linear transformation. The act on some other vector space by transforming those vectors in various ways. Both are useful so it's worth exploring them.
